# Do we have "founded"?

Tags: word-usage

I was going to write:

> if the founded rule classifies the node as "content", it will be added ...."

Any rule in a list matching some criteria will be returned by a `searchRule` method.  I can use *if the matched rule*, but I was surprised as I googled and found that we don't have "founded".... why? then what is used for such things?

> The founded person ....
>
> The founded object ...

Comment: **found** is the past participle of **find**, **founded** is past participle of the verb **found**, I guess. Thus, I think founded person sounds odd !

Comment: @Cardinal Oh! didn't know such close verbs they are!

Comment: It is cool, I had the same problem when I read the question at the first time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if the matched rule,

Here, **matched** is the past participle of the verb *match*. Likewise, **found** is the past participle of the verb *find*, so you actually want **found**

> if the found rule classifies the node as content...

However, it sounds more natural (to my ears anyways) to say

> if the rule found classifies the node as content...

Note: "founded" is a word with a different meaning. It is the past participle and past tense of the verb "to found" meaning to establish.

> The city was founded in 1875